# Visual Studio: Keyboard 'locks', no typing possible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio 2012 sometimes suddenly the keyboard "locks": I cannot write in the C# text  editor anymore! Pressing the cursor keys results in switching between the docked windows.

It behaves as if some control  key is stuck, but pressing Ctrl, Alt, Scroll-Lock didn't help either.

A restart of VStudio helps.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Have you tried to deactivate Microsoft's Productivity Power Tools? Do you have installed any ReSharper?

Comment: @Marek Nothing fancy there. Just Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug with VS 2012 at the time. Later on, a service pack removed the bug.